# How to use packages that still use deprecated package scipy.wave?

Tags: python, python-2.7, installation

Some old packages need deprecated `scipy.weave` package, like `pydelay`.
Installing weave from pip does not work for them.
What is the solution?

Edit:

```
In [1]: import pydelay
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-b743be9b35c7> in <module>()
----> 1 import pydelay

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pydelay/__init__.py in <module>()
      7 Last update: 23.10.2009
      8 """
----> 9 from _dde23 import dde23
     10 #from constantStepper import dde3
     11 __all__ = ['dde23', 'gen_disconts']

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pydelay/_dde23.py in <module>()
     30 
     31 import numpy as np
---> 32 from scipy import weave
     33 from scipy.interpolate import splrep, splev, spalde
     34 import math

ImportError: cannot import name weave
```

[Here is mentioned that :](https://github.com/scipy/weave)
Weave is the stand-alone version of the deprecated Scipy submodule `scipy.weave`.

**Solution:**
I removed the package, replaced the scipy.weave by weave in files and reinstalled by `setup.py` file. that's all.

Comment: Using deprecated APIs does still work, why exactly don't you want to use it?

Comment: I can not import the package. I added the import error. I cant also `import scipy.weave`, `import weave` works.

Comment: Ah, then the word is "dropped functionality", not "deprecated". Deprecated implies that it's still there, and just raises DeprecationWarnings when used.

Comment: Virtual environment

Comment: How do you install pydelay? It's not on pipy.

Comment: No it has a setup.py file. I doubted about the stupid solution that I tried. Yes it works by just replacing scipy.weave by weave!